# Angular material design, styling auto complete and textbox with same style

Tags: angularjs, responsive-design

I am building an angularjs responsive design application.I have used ng-material design.However the auto complete component and textbox have different style.I could not figure out how to position both component with same style and size.
Could you please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: please create a code pen with the text box and auto complete components in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial']);

app.controller('AppCtrl', AppCtrl);

function AppCtrl($timeout, $q) {
var self = this;

// list of `state` value/display objects
self.states = loadAll();
self.selectedItem = null;
self.searchText = null;
self.querySearch = querySearch;

// ******************************
// Internal methods
// ******************************

/**
 * Search for states... use $timeout to simulate
 * remote dataservice call.
 */
function querySearch(query) {
    var results = query ? self.states.filter(createFilterFor(query)) : [];
    return results;
}

/**
 * Build `states` list of key/value pairs
 */
function loadAll() {
    var allStates = 'Alabama, Alaska, Arizona, Arkansas, California, Colorado, Connecticut, Delaware,\
          Florida, Georgia, Hawaii, Idaho, Illinois, Indiana, Iowa, Kansas, Kentucky, Louisiana,\
          Maine, Maryland, Massachusetts, Michigan, Minnesota, Mississippi, Missouri, Montana,\
          Nebraska, Nevada, New Hampshire, New Jersey, New Mexico, New York, North Carolina,\
          North Dakota, Ohio, Oklahoma, Oregon, Pennsylvania, Rhode Island, South Carolina,\
          South Dakota, Tennessee, Texas, Utah, Vermont, Virginia, Washington, West Virginia,\
          Wisconsin, Wyoming';

    return allStates.split(/, +/g).map(function (state) {
        return {
            value: state.toLowerCase(),
            display: state
        };
    });
}

/**
 * Create filter function for a query string
 */
function createFilterFor(query) {
    var lowercaseQuery = angular.lowercase(query);

    return function filterFn(state) {
        return (state.value.indexOf(lowercaseQuery) === 0);
    };

}
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.9.4/angular-material.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.9.4/angular-material.min.js"></script>
 <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body layout="column" ng-app="MyApp">

    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl as ctrl" layout="column" ng-cloak="" class="autocompletedemoFloatingLabel" ng-app="MyApp">
        <md-content class="md-padding">
            <form ng-submit="$event.preventDefault()" name="searchForm">
                <p>The following example demonstrates floating labels being used as a normal form element.</p>
                <div layout-gt-sm="row">
                    <md-input-container flex="">
                        <label>Name</label>
                        <input type="text">
                    </md-input-container>
                    <md-autocomplete flex="" required="" md-input-name="autocompleteField" md-input-minlength="2" md-input-maxlength="18" md-no-cache="ctrl.noCache" md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem" md-search-text="ctrl.searchText" md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)" md-item-text="item.display" md-floating-label="Favorite state">
                        <md-item-template>
                            <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText">{{item.display}}</span>
                        </md-item-template>
                        <div ng-messages="searchForm.autocompleteField.$error" ng-if="searchForm.autocompleteField.$touched">
                            <div ng-message="required">You <b>must</b> have a favorite state.</div>
                            <div ng-message="minlength">Your entry is not long enough.</div>
                            <div ng-message="maxlength">Your entry is too long.</div>
                        </div>
                    </md-autocomplete>
                </div>
            </form>
        </md-content>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Let me know if any issue presists